# Correct Market Value of a Stock

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, stock-markets

Thanks for looking into my post.

I am new to the stock investment.

Current Microsoft book value is 15$ but the Market value is 198$

How to decide value of the stock?

How can I say its overvalued and whats the original value of the stock?

Which parameter decides its worth to buy or not?

Comment: Double post https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/126921/book-value-vs-current-market-value